# i want to create a picklist which contains account and contact

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

i want to create a picklist which contains account and contact..when we select account then it shows account list (name,website,email)..and when we select contact then it will shows contact list(name,mobile,email)..

i have alredy write below code but it not shows desired result

```
public class PickAccountContact{
 public string selectdMaster{get;set;}
 public List<contact> listcontacts{get;set;}
 public List<Account> listAccount{get;set;}

 public List<SelectOption> getMasterOption() {
   List<SelectOption> Options=new List<SelectOption>();
   options.add(new selectoption('Acc','Account'));
   options.add(new selectoption('Con','Contact'));
   return options;
 }
}
```

page:

```
<apex:page controller="PickAccountContact" sidebar="false">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:outputPanel >
        <apex:outputLabel value="Account/Contact"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <apex:selectList value="{!selectdMaster}" size="1">
          <apex:selectOptions value="{!MasterOption}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
      </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add actionsupport for event onchange.

```
<apex:page controller="PickAccountContact" sidebar="false">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:outputPanel >
        <apex:outputLabel value="Account/Contact"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <apex:selectList value="{!selectdMaster}" size="1">
          <apex:selectOptions value="{!MasterOption}"/>
          <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="list,list2"/>
        </apex:selectList>
      </apex:outputPanel>
      <apex:outputPanel id="list" rendered="{!selectdMaster = 'Acc'}>
          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listAccount}" var="a">

            <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/> 
            <apex:column value="{!a.website}"/> 
            <apex:column value="{!a.email}"/> 
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
      </apex:outputPanel>
      <apex:outputPanel id="list2" rendered="{!selectdMaster = 'Con'}>
          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listcontacts}" var="c">

            <apex:column value="{!c.name}"/> 
            <apex:column value="{!c.mobile}"/> 
            <apex:column value="{!c.email}"/> 
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
      </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```